# Understanding a method of finding the highest common factor of two polynomials (Elementary Algebra by Hall & Knight)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the chapter on Highest Common Factors (HCF's), a method is given for finding the HCF of compound expressions.

[image]

Could someone please explain the explanation given at the end of the page? The given explanation makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to understand if written out differently.

We have $8x^3-2x^2-53x-39$ and $4x^3-3x^2-24x-9$.

To eliminate $x^3$ from the first equation we subtract twice the second equation from the first to obtain $$4x^2-5x-21.$$
We can now eliminate $x^3$ fro the second equation by subtracting $x$ times $4x^2-5x-21.$ This gives$$2x^2-3x-9.$$

You should be able to see these calculations in the table. The same process is now carried out with the two quadratics.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also encountered the same impediment of understanding the method of finding HCF in compound algebraic expressions. However, by brainstorming and researching this topic, I have grasped it thoroughly. This method is identical to that of finding HCF of natural numbers using long division method.

**Step 1:** Arrange the two given expressions in descending powers of any variable you choose. Here the expressions : *4$x^3$ - 3$x^2$ - 24x - 9* and *8$x^3$ - 2$x^2$ - 53x - 39* are already arranged in such a sequence. 

 
**Step 2:** Examine the degrees of the two expressions and choose the term of highest degree with a smaller coefficient as the divisor. The degree of the two given expressions is 3. Now among these expressions, we choose the expression *4$x^3$ - 3$x^2$ - 24x - 9* as our divisor. And, the other expression becomes our dividend. 

 
**Step 3:** Divide the dividend by the divisor, and the remainder obtained would be : *4$x^2$ - 5x - 21*. Next, considering this remainder as our divisor and the previous divisor as our dividend, we work out our next division: 

$\dfrac{4$x^3$ - 3$x^2$ - 24x - 9}{4$x^2$ - 5x - 21}$

**Step 4:** The remainder of this division would come out to be: 2$x^2$ - 3x - 9. Again, we make this as our divisor and the previous divisor as our dividend to proceed with the succeding division.

We continue with this process until the remainder is zero. The final divisor (when the remainder is 0) would be the HCF.

Instead of representing it in columns, I would highly recommend you carry out different polynomial divisions separately as explained in the steps above. Another rule to keep in mind while calculating HCF of complex expressions is that all remainders in the steps must contain the HCF within themselves, since there are a few additional steps required when the expressions take up a different form. Moreover, don't leave the polynomial division until the degree of divisor > degree of remainder unless there is a need to introduce a fractional term. If you bear these points while calculating, you will move seamlessly.Remember, the basics of this method will remain the similar, even with other complex expressions; so stick to these basics. The proof of this method is provided in the same chapter of ELEMENTARY ALGEBRA by H.S HALL and S.R KNIGHT is provided below.